# I need to extract data from certain columns in one workbook and append it to existing data in another workbook

Tags: vba

Honest, I've searched and searched and while there may be an existing answer to a similar question I can't seem to find it. That said:

- I have data in two different workbooks and I need to copy data from a select number of non-contiguous columns in a file generated every week and append it to specific columns of existing data in a master file
- I receive a new file every week named results.data.xls and it contains 5 columns of data with a variable record count - some weeks it could be two rows, others it could be 200+
- I want to be able to copy the data that appears in column "B" (`'PRODUCT_FORMAT_CAPACITY'`), column "D" (`'CUSTOMER'`) and column "E" (`BILLTO_CUSTOMER_NUM`) in results.data.xls and append it to existing data in similarly titled columns in master.data.xls
- Recording a macro doesn't get me very far as I clearly can't get it to understand the need to append data - I've seen VBA commands that will enable this but I can't figure out how to modify the simple recording to get it to do what I need

Answer (score 0):

The macro recorder is perfect for discovering the syntax of complex, single-statement keyboard commands.  But if you do A then B then C, the recorder records these as three completely independent commands even if they are phases of a single command.

To test the code below:

- I created workbook 'master.data.xls' and, within it, worksheet 'Combined'. You do not mention your worksheet names so I have made up my own. I headed three columns 'PRODUCT_FORMAT_CAPACITY', 'CUSTOMER' and 'BILLTO_CUSTOMER_NUM' but not columns B, D and E. I placed some random data in these columns.
- I created workbook 'results.data.xls' and, within it, worksheet 'Week'. I headed columns B, D and E 'PRODUCT_FORMAT_CAPACITY', 'CUSTOMER' and 'BILLTO_CUSTOMER_NUM'. I placed some random data in these columns.
- I created the macro in a separate workbook.  I prefer holding my macros in separate workbooks so the users (1) are not bothered with them and (2) cannot change them.

You do not say if you are new to programming or new to VBA.  I have assumed you are new to programming.  Most of the code below is about checking your assumptions and failing gracefully if things are not as expected.

There are several alternative techniques for finding the bottom row or rightmost column none of which work in every situation. I have picked one of those techniques for the code below. See this answer of mine for a demonstration of some of the alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18220846/973283.

Hope this helps.

```
' "Option Explicit" stops a mispelt name becoming a declaration.  Without
' "Option Explicit" the following will define a new variable Conut.  Such
' errors can be very difficult to find:
'    Dim Count As Long
'    Conut = Count + 1
Option Explicit

  ' Use constants for values that will not change during a run of the macro
  ' particularly if you have to use them several times or if purpose of the
  ' value is not obvious.  "Cells(Row,2)" is a lot harder to understand than
  ' "Cells(Row,ColResultProduct)".  I have used WBkMasterName several times.
  ' If the workbook is renamed, changing the constant declaration fixes the
  ' problem.
  Const ColResultProduct As Long = 2
  Const ColBillToName As String = "BILLTO_CUSTOMER_NUM"
  Const ColCustomerName As String = "CUSTOMER"
  Const ColProductName As String = "PRODUCT_FORMAT_CAPACITY"
  Const WBkMasterName As String = "master.data.xls"
  Const WBkResultName As String = "results.data.xls"
  Const WShtMasterName As String = "Combined"
  Const WShtResultName As String = "Week"

  ' My naming convention is ABC where A is the type (Col for column, WBk for
  ' workbook, etc), B identifies the particular A (for example, for Col, B
  ' identifies the worksheet) and C identifies which AB if there is more than
  ' one (for ColMaster I have ColMasterProduct, ColMasterBillTo, ColMasterCrnt
  ' (Crnt = Current), etc.  You may not like my naming convention. Fine, pick
  ' your own or, better still, agree one with colleagues.  Conventions mean
  ' you can look at the program you wrote twelve months ago or your colleague
  ' wrote and understand the variables.

  ' My comments tell you my objective or my reason for selecting method A and
  ' not B. They do not explain VBA syntax.  For example, once you know the
  ' Workbooks.Open statement exists, it is easy to find an explanation of its
  ' syntax within the VBA help or via an internet search,

Sub Demo()

  Dim ColMasterBillTo As Long
  Dim ColMasterCrnt As Long
  Dim ColMasterCustomer As Long
  Dim ColMasterLast As Long
  Dim ColMasterProduct As Long
  Dim ColResultBillTo As Long
  Dim ColResultCustomer As String
  Dim CountMasterColFoundCrnt As Long
  Dim CountMasterColFoundTotal As Long
  Dim InxWBkCrnt As Long
  Dim PathCrnt As String
  Dim RngResult As Range
  Dim RowMasterNext As Long
  Dim RowResultLast As Long
  Dim TempStg As String
  Dim WBkMaster As Workbook
  Dim WBkResult As Workbook
  Dim WShtMaster As Worksheet
  Dim WShtResult As Worksheet

  ' ThisWorkbook identifies the workbook containing the macro.
  ' I will assume the data workbooks are in the same folder as
  ' the macro workbook.
  PathCrnt = ThisWorkbook.Path

  ' You do not want to run this macro when someone has the data workbooks open
  ' so check for them being within the collection of open workbooks.
  For InxWBkCrnt = 1 To Workbooks.Count
    If Workbooks(InxWBkCrnt).Name = WBkMasterName Then
      Call MsgBox("Please close workbook '" & WBkMasterName & _
                                   "' before running this macro.", vbOKOnly)
      Exit Sub
    End If
    If Workbooks(InxWBkCrnt).Name = WBkResultName Then
      Call MsgBox("Please close workbook '" & WBkResultName & _
                                   "' before running this macro.", vbOKOnly)
      Exit Sub
    End If
  Next

  ' The next blocks of code check that the workbooks exist and contain the
  ' expected worksheets with the expected columns. You may think that this
  ' code is unnecessary and I hope you are right.  However, if something is
  ' wrong, do you want your macro to fail unexpectedly with a yellow statement
  ' and an error message a programmer may find difficult to understand or
  ' corrupt data because columns have moved or do you want the macro to close
  ' tidily with an error message that the user understands?

  ' "On Error Resume Next" Statement "On Error GoTo 0" switches off normal
  ' error processing for "Statement". You can then check if "Statement"
  ' has had the expected result. Some statements set Err.Number and
  ' Err.Description if they fail but Workbooks.Open does not.

  ' You can use Dir$() to check for the file existing but (1) I think the
  ' approach below is marginally easier and (2) Dir$() checks for existence
  ' not openability.

  ' Try to open data workbooks.  Report failure to the user.
  On Error Resume Next
  Workbooks.Open PathCrnt & "\" & WBkMasterName
  On Error GoTo 0

  If ActiveWorkbook.Name = ThisWorkbook.Name Then
    Call MsgBox("I was unable to open workbook " & _
                                              WBkMasterName & "'.", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  End If
  Set WBkMaster = ActiveWorkbook

  On Error Resume Next
  Workbooks.Open PathCrnt & "\" & WBkResultName
  On Error GoTo 0

  If ActiveWorkbook.Name = WBkMaster.Name Then
    Call MsgBox("I was unable to open workbook '" & _
                                              WBkResultName & "'.", vbOKOnly)
      ' Tidy up by closing open workbook and releasing resource
      WBkMaster.Close SaveChanges:=False
      Set WBkMaster = Nothing
    Exit Sub
  End If
  Set WBkResult = ActiveWorkbook

  ' Try to reference worksheets
  With WBkMaster
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WShtMaster = .Worksheets(WShtMasterName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If WShtMaster Is Nothing Then
      Call MsgBox("Workbook '" & WBkMasterName & "' does not contain " & _
                  "worksheet '" & WShtMasterName & "'.", vbOKOnly)
      WBkMaster.Close SaveChanges:=False
      WBkResult.Close SaveChanges:=False
      Set WBkMaster = Nothing
      Set WBkResult = Nothing
      Exit Sub
    End If
  End With

  With WBkResult
    On Error Resume Next
    Set WShtResult = .Worksheets(WShtResultName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If WShtResult Is Nothing Then
      Call MsgBox("Workbook '" & WBkResultName & "' does not contain " & _
                  "worksheet '" & WShtResultName & "'.", vbOKOnly)
      WBkMaster.Close SaveChanges:=False
      WBkResult.Close SaveChanges:=False
      Set WBkMaster = Nothing
      Set WBkResult = Nothing
      Exit Sub
    End If
  End With

  With WShtResult

    ' I have defined 'ColResultProduct' with a constant.  That will be the best
    ' approach unless you know to expect a particular type of change.

    ' I use "Debug.Assert Boolean-expression" extensively during development.
    ' In particular, I place "Debug.Assert False" above every alternative path
    ' through my code. When I hit a "Debug.Assert False" during testing, I
    ' comment it out.  If any remain at the end of testing I know that either
    ' my testing was not as thorough as it should be or I have allowed for
    ' a situation that does not exist.  Either way, the code needs review.
    ' Leaving a "Debug.Assert" statement in code you release to users would be
    ' very unprofessional.
    Debug.Assert .Cells(1, ColResultProduct).Value = ColProductName

    ' In a Cells object, the column can be a number or a letter.  Use whichever
    ' you prefer. I do not like statements like this buried in the code. This
    ' should be a constant statement at the top of the module.
    ColResultCustomer = "D"

    If .Cells(1, ColResultCustomer).Value <> ColCustomerName Then
      ' Note the use of property Address as an easy way of converting a VBA
      ' style address to a user style address.  Note also the use of Replace to
      ' remove the dollar signs from "$D$1" to give "D1"
      Call MsgBox("Cell " & Replace(.Cells(1, ColResultCustomer).Address, "$", "") _
           & " of worksheet '" & WShtResultName & "' of workbook '" & _
           WBkResultName & "' is not " & ColCustomerName & ".", vbOKOnly)
      WBkMaster.Close SaveChanges:=False
      WBkResult.Close SaveChanges:=False
      Set WBkMaster = Nothing
      Set WBkResult = Nothing
      Exit Sub
    End If

    ColResultBillTo = 5         ' Again, this should be a constant
    If .Cells(1, ColResultBillTo).Value <> ColBillToName Then
      Call MsgBox("Cell " & Replace(.Cells(1, ColResultBillTo).Address, "$", "") _
           & " of worksheet '" & WShtResultName & "' of workbook '" & _
           WBkResultName & "' is not " & ColBillToName & ".", vbOKOnly)
      WBkMaster.Close SaveChanges:=False
      WBkResult.Close SaveChanges:=False
      Set WBkMaster = Nothing
      Set WBkResult = Nothing
      Exit Sub
    End If
  End With

  With WShtMaster

    ' Do not consider anything like this code unless columns are moved
    ' regularly. It is so easy to waste time preparing for situations that will
    ' never occur. You could amend three constants many times more quickly than
    ' you can get code like this debugged.  I have code like this because I
    ' have situations in which columns moving is likely to occur and I do
    ' not want my diverse users coming back to me when it does.

    ColMasterLast = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    CountMasterColFoundTotal = 0
    ColMasterBillTo = 0
    ColMasterCustomer = 0
    ColMasterProduct = 0
    ' Look for the three headers and record their columns.  Record
    ' number of headers found.
    For ColMasterCrnt = 1 To ColMasterLast
      If .Cells(1, ColMasterCrnt).Value = ColBillToName Then
        CountMasterColFoundTotal = CountMasterColFoundTotal + 1
        ColMasterBillTo = ColMasterCrnt
      ElseIf .Cells(1, ColMasterCrnt).Value = ColCustomerName Then
        CountMasterColFoundTotal = CountMasterColFoundTotal + 1
        ColMasterCustomer = ColMasterCrnt
      ElseIf .Cells(1, ColMasterCrnt).Value = ColProductName Then
        CountMasterColFoundTotal = CountMasterColFoundTotal + 1
        ColMasterProduct = ColMasterCrnt
      End If
    Next
    If CountMasterColFoundTotal <> 3 Then
      ' One or more column has not been found
      CountMasterColFoundCrnt = 3
      TempStg = "I cannot find column headings"
      If ColMasterProduct = 0 Then
        'Debug.Assert False
        TempStg = TempStg & " " & ColProductName
        CountMasterColFoundCrnt = CountMasterColFoundCrnt - 1
        If CountMasterColFoundCrnt - 1 >= CountMasterColFoundTotal Then
          'Debug.Assert False
          TempStg = TempStg & " or"
        'Else
          'Debug.Assert False
        End If
      'Else
        'Debug.Assert False
      End If
      If ColMasterCustomer = 0 Then
        'Debug.Assert False
        TempStg = TempStg & " " & ColCustomerName
        CountMasterColFoundCrnt = CountMasterColFoundCrnt - 1
        If CountMasterColFoundCrnt - 1 >= CountMasterColFoundTotal Then
          'Debug.Assert False
          TempStg = TempStg & " or"
        'Else
          Debug.Assert False
        End If
      'Else
        'Debug.Assert False
      End If
      If ColMasterBillTo = 0 Then
        'Debug.Assert False
        TempStg = TempStg & " " & ColBillToName
      'Else
        'Debug.Assert False
      End If
      TempStg = TempStg & " in row 1 of worksheet '" & _
                WShtMasterName & "' of workbook '" & WBkMasterName & "'."
      Call MsgBox(TempStg, vbOKOnly)
      WBkMaster.Close SaveChanges:=False
      WBkResult.Close SaveChanges:=False
      Set WBkMaster = Nothing
      Set WBkResult = Nothing
      Exit Sub
    End If
  End With

  ' If get here then both workbooks are as required.

  ' Find last row of results worksheet and next row of master worksheet
  ' Copy product column from results to master
  With WShtResult
    RowResultLast = .UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
    Set RngResult = .Range(.Cells(2, ColResultProduct), _
                           .Cells(RowResultLast, ColResultProduct))
  End With
  With WShtMaster
    RowMasterNext = .UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    RngResult.Copy Destination:=.Cells(RowMasterNext, ColMasterProduct)
  End With

  ' Copy customer column from results to master
  With WShtResult
    Set RngResult = .Range(.Cells(2, ColResultCustomer), _
                           .Cells(RowResultLast, ColResultCustomer))
  End With
  With WShtMaster
    RngResult.Copy Destination:=.Cells(RowMasterNext, ColMasterCustomer)
  End With

  ' Copy bill to column from results to master
  With WShtResult
    Set RngResult = .Range(.Cells(2, ColResultBillTo), _
                           .Cells(RowResultLast, ColResultBillTo))
  End With
  With WShtMaster
    RngResult.Copy Destination:=.Cells(RowMasterNext, ColMasterBillTo)
  End With

  WBkMaster.Close SaveChanges:=True
  WBkResult.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```