# Copy several rows from excel sheet and paste into same row on new excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Could anyone provide some VBA code please that would facilitate the following request?

I would like to copy six rows and paste these into a new sheet on the same row. I have hundreds of rows, hence the request for code. It would need to copy the first six rows to one row, the next six to the second row etc. Each row to be copied has nine cells as in the example below.

```
ColA            |ColB           |ColC|ColD|ColE|ColF|ColG|ColH|ColI
Separatecombined|Smoothedremoved|1.00|1.00|99  |90  |95  |98  |accuracy
```

Many thanks.

Andy

Comment: Im sorry, I have no code. Thats beyond my skill set. What I have done is started doing this manually. Having read that VBA can help with laborious tasks such as this in Excel, I thought I would reach out and ask. Many thanks. Andy

Comment: Try turning on the macro recorder (http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html) and running through a few cycles of your current process -- some patterns should definitely reveal themselves. Try adjusting that code to achieve what you want, and post any questions you have here -- we're happy to help!

Comment: Thanks for the question. I would like each cell that is copied to be pasted into an individual cell. Therefore for each set of six rows copied, the resulting one row would have 54 cells populated. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This site exists to allow programmers to help other programmers develop their skills. Sometimes significant pieces of code are provided in answers but this is not a free coding site.

The macro to perform the actions you require is so small and simple, I do not believe you know any VBA at all.  Normally I would respond to a question like this by telling you how to write the macro you seek.  However, your requirement is so simple it was easier to code than to provide instructions.  you must learn VBA if you want to use macros.  It will not take long to learn the basics and the time spent will quickly repay itself.  Search for "VBA Excel tutorial". There are many to choose from. Try a few and complete the one that matches your learning style. I prefer books. I visited a large library and reviewed all the Excel VBA primers. I then bought the one I preferred.

The first task is to find the last used row in the source worksheet.  I have used the method that is normally the most convenient.  However, there are several method of finding the last row or column and none work in every situation.  The method I have chosen may not work with your data.  This [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18220846/973283) includes a macro, `FindFinal`, which uses a variety of methods and shows when they fail.  This will help you choose an alternative if necessary.

You then need nested for loops to move the data.

The macro below is the one you asked for but I am not sure it is the macro you want.  If I had your requirement, I would want source row 1 (the column headings) duplicated six times and then rows 2 to last copied across.  I leave you with the task of creating a copy of my inner loop to achieve this duplication.  Come back with questions if necessary but I believe forcing you to make this amendment will help you understand my code and help you develop your own skills.

Good luck and welcome to the joys of programming.

```
Option Explicit
Sub MergeRows()

   Dim ColDestCrnt As Long
   Dim RowDestCrnt As Long
   Dim RowSrcCrnt As Long
   Dim RowSrcLast As Long
   Dim RowWithinGroupNum As Long
   Dim WshtDest As Worksheet

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   Set WshtDest = Worksheets("Destination")

   With Worksheets("Source")

     ' Find last used row of worksheet.  This assumes column "A"
     ' contains a value in every used row.
     RowSrcLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

     RowDestCrnt = 1

     ' Loop for each set of six rows.  Unless the source worksheet
     ' contains a multiple of six rows, the last set will involve the
     ' copying of empty rows.  I decided it was less effort to copy
     ' these empty rows than to include code to not copy them
     For RowSrcCrnt = 1 To RowSrcLast Step 6

       ' Loop for each row within a set
       For RowWithinGroupNum = 0 To 5

         ' Calculate the start column in the destination worksheet
         ColDestCrnt = (RowWithinGroupNum) * 6 + 1

         ' Copy all six cells from the current source row to the six cells
         ' starting at the appropriate column in the destination row
         .Range(.Cells(RowSrcCrnt + RowWithinGroupNum, 1), _
                .Cells(RowSrcCrnt + RowWithinGroupNum, 6)).Copy _
                      Destination:=WshtDest.Cells(RowDestCrnt, ColDestCrnt)

       Next RowWithinGroupNum

       ' Step the destination row ready for the next set
       RowDestCrnt = RowDestCrnt + 1

     Next RowSrcCrnt

   End With

End Sub
```